# I am in trouble, I don't want to reinstall the OS again

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install python3.7 in Ubuntu, so I removed python3.4 by

`sudo apt-get remove python3.4

sudo apt-get purge python3.4`

Only then I find something wrong, some system files is written by python3.4.

By typing `sudo apt-get install python3.7-minimal`, I got `unable to locate python3.7-minimal
couldn't find any package by regex python3.7-minimal`

I am really scared, I don't want to reinstall the OS again!

What can I do?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3.7`

Comment: the output of sudo apt-get install python3.7 is unable to locate package3.7   couldnot find ang package by regex python3.1

Comment: Great. Add that to your question. Make sure you copy and paste the output because there appear to be a couple of mistakes in what you typed. That way there's a problem to fix. This site is geared towards Questions and Answers, not support.

Comment: My advice is to install python3.4 again so that the packages which need it are happy. Then work on the question of how to get Python 3.7.

Comment: I tried to install python3.4 ,but it says unable to fetch some archives,                     I cannot connect the network due to the lack of some system files.

Comment: You're using a version of Ubuntu that's over five years old, and which reached end-of-life several months ago. It's time to install a newer release anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that removing Python has caused any damage to your system. If you're seeing evidence of that, then please ask a question about that evidence.

However, Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 14 is a very new Python on a very old Ubuntu. There certainly isn't an official package from Ubuntu, and even the popular PPAs from [Jonothon F](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.7) and [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) do not support that combination.

If you can't upgrade to a newer Ubuntu, then you'll have to try compiling Python 3.7 yourself. There are plenty of guides on this, but it is not usually for the faint hearted. You can start [here](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/).